# react bootstrap carousel Items "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

**Bootsrap carousel Items unique key error.i added the right place my key.but error won't go away.
here is my error.**
[image: key error]

when i inspect in elements,i think i added to the right place.but react giving me warning over and over again.
[image: element]

this is my code.

```js
  return (
    <>
      <Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect} keyboard slide touch wrap pause={false}>
        {movie.map((m) =>
          <Carousel.Item key={m.id}>
            <img
              src={m.background_image_original}
              alt={m.title_english}
            />
            <Carousel.Caption>
              <CaptionDiv >
                <h4>suggestions</h4>
                <h2>{m.title}</h2>
                <CaptioninfoDiv className='mr-auto'>
                  <p className='mr-3'>{m.year}</p>

                  {m.genres.map((g) =>
                    <p className='mr-1'>{g}</p>

                  )}

                  <p className='ml-3'>{m.runtime} min</p>
                </CaptioninfoDiv>
                <CaptionInfoMain >
                  <p>{m.summary.slice(0, 200)}<Readmore> Read more...</Readmore> </p>
                  <a href={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${m.yt_trailer_code}`} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" className='btn btn-danger btn-lg'>Watch Trailer</a>
                </CaptionInfoMain>
              </CaptionDiv>

            </Carousel.Caption>

          </Carousel.Item>

        )}



      </Carousel>
    </>
  )
```

Comment: This line doesn't have a key: `<p className='mr-1'>{g}</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `movie.map((m) =>` is giving keys to its children, but your `m.genres.map((g) =>` is not. Assuming that there aren't any duplicate generes, you can use

```
{
    m.genres.map((g) =>
        <p className='mr-1' key={g}>{g}</p>
    )
}
```